# If $|f(i)|<1$, then $\exists u,v \in \mathbb{R}, \ f(u+iv)=0, \ (u^2+v^2+1)^2<4v^2+1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> $f(x)$ is a real polynomial with leading coeffient $1$.
> For $i=\sqrt{-1}$, prove that if $|f(i)|<1$ then $\exists u,v \in \mathbb{R}, \ f(u+iv)=0, \ (u^2+v^2+1)^2<4v^2+1$.

My attempt:

Let $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ and $z=u+iv$ is a root of $f(x)=0$.

$$|f(i)|^2=(a_0-a_2+a_4-a_6+\cdots)^2+(a_1-a_3+a_5-a_7+\cdots)^2<1$$

$$ \begin{align}
&(u^2+v^2+1)^2<4v^2+1 \\
& \Longleftrightarrow(u^2+(v+1)^2)(u^2+(v-1)^2)<1 \\
& \Longleftrightarrow |z+i||z-i|<1 \\
& \Longleftrightarrow |z^2+1|<1
\end{align}$$

... and I don't know how these are to be connected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove it by contraposition, write $f(x) = \prod_{k = 1}^n (x - a_k)\prod_{j = 1}^m (x - b_j)\left(x - \overline{b_j}\right)$ with $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $k$ and $b_j \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ for all $j$. Assume that for all root $r$ of $f$, $|r^2 + 1| \geqslant 1$. It means that for every $j$, $\left|(i - b_j)\left(i - \overline{b_j}\right)\right| = |(i - b_j)(-i - b_j)| = |b_j^2 + 1| \geqslant 1$ and for all $k$, $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ so $|i - a_k| = \sqrt{1 + a_k^2} \geqslant 1$. We deduce that,
$$
|f(i)| = \left|\prod_{k = 1}^n (x - a_k)\prod_{j = 1}^m (x - b_j)\left(x - \overline{b_j}\right)\right| \geqslant 1.
$$
By contraposition, if $|f(i)| < 1$, then $f$ has a root $r$ such that $|r^2 + 1| < 1$, and we can even choose it non real (i.e. non zero in this case).